# "LoaderLock was detected" with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have a couple of MVC projects which use SQL CE 4.0 and Entity Framework. Since moving to Visual Studio 2012 I keep getting the following error (not every time, but frequently)

LoaderLock was detected

Attempting managed execution inside OS Loader lock. Do not attempt to run managed code inside a DllMain or image initialization function since doing so can cause the application to hang.

The error does not occur if I go back to using VS 2010, which makes me fairly certain it is an issue with Visual Studio rather than my code, but I would like someone to confirm that for me!

**Edit**

The problem always seems to occur when the Dispose() method of the dbcontext is called. Here is a screenshot of the Exception Assistant:

[image: Exception Assistant]

Comment: Or, VS2012 is being more careful than VS2010 about unsafe constructs.

Comment: No call stack to look at so hard to help you.  In general, LoaderLock tends to produce false warnings.  You can turn it off with Debug + Exceptions, MDAs, LoaderLock checkbox.

Comment: @Hans, there doesn't seem to be a call stack (I've added a screenshot of the Exception Assistant to my post). I assume the problem is in unmanaged code.

Comment: This also happens with Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web using MVC projects which use SQL CE 4.0 and Entity Framework. I have been continuing (F5) and the application still works. I have not found the option to turn the message off in Express yet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I [switch this off](http://harriyott.com/2006/08/loaderlock-was-detected). As it is warning that the application could hang, if your program doesn't hang, then you're probably fine.

> The problem can be solved in the same way though, by switching off the
>   MDA:
>
> Debug -> Exceptions -> Managed Debug Assistants
>
> and unchecking the LoaderLock item.

Answer (score 5):

I also had a problem with `LoaderLock` when I was working with some external dll in my C# application.

- for the **.NET 3.5** I just uncheck `Thrown option` in `Exceptions menu` ([Loader lock error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56642/loader-lock-error))
- for the **.NET 4.0** I added `<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">` in `app.config`

Comment: I am using this for the moment, and it worked great. Had the issue with VS 2012, v4.5 and Sql CE 4.0.  Here is a link with more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604663/what-does-uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy-do-in-the-net-4-config/2467255#2467255

Answer (score 0):

It may happen with compiler warning [C4747](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4747?view=msvc-170).

To avoid this, make DllMain unmanaged.

For example:

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#pragma unmanaged // <- add this line just after include to make code after this be unmanaged.
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

or

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#pragma managed(push, off) // <- add this line before function DllMain
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
#pragma managed(pop) // <- add this line after function DllMain to make code below managed.
```