# DLL initialization stops the program

Tags: dll, dll-injection, dllregistration

Have a nice day!

I have problem with DLL injection.
There are two same computers with Windows 10. I inject (new thread is created by the program itself) my DLL into the same program installed on both PC. I do some initialization and calculating offsets on DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH. Injection at the first PC works fine. However, injection at the second PC stops all program until I finish initialization and return TRUE. In other words, in the first case the program continues to run, and in the second case, it is waiting for the initialization of the library.
I do the same things, but I don't understand why do I need to finish initialization in the second case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874324/what-is-a-loader-lock

Comment: Thanks a lot, now i've got it. But quite strange that the same code, same calls and the same things behave different on the different PC..